# Batch script not processing input parameter to nested batch file

Tags: batch-file, nested

I'm trying to build a commandline cross compile batchscript to compile my program in Visual Studio 2010 (this is the only option since msbuild will not work with setup files). The batch script looks like this (buildall.bat):

```
if %1 == x86 goto x86
if %1 == x64 goto x64

:x86
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 < crosscompile.bat x86
goto :eof

:x64
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64 < crosscompile.bat x64
goto :eof
```

Where crosscompile.bat is a file that contains the actual build commands below

```
devenv Studd.sln /clean "Release|%1"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
devenv Studd.sln /rebuild "Release|%1"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

**The issue is when I run this command:**

```
buildall.bat x64
```

It ends up running this:

```
D:\x>if "x64" == "" goto all
D:\x>if x64 == x86 goto x86
D:\x>if x64 == x64 goto x64
D:\x>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64  x64 0<crosscompile.bat
Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" [option]
where [option] is: x86 | ia64 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_ia64

For example:
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_ia64
D:\x>devenv Studd.sln /clean "Release|%1"
'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
D:\x>IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
D:\x>goto :eof
```

The problem lies here

> ```
> D:\x>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64  x64 0<crosscompile.bat
> ```

My original batch script says:

> ```
> %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64 < crosscompile.bat x64
> ```

I can't seem to understand why it takes the x64 after crosscompile.bat (which is the parameter to it) and puts it before it and introduce a 0?

If I write 2 separate scripts for crosscompile.bat (x86 and x64) where I don't pass any parameters to it, it works fine. But I would like to reuse crosscompile.bat so how can I get this work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd /k vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 < crosscompile.bat x64
```

This means: start a cmd instance with the input stream redirected from the file (the file in disk, not the execution of) `crosscompile.bat` and the arguments to the cmd instance are the rest of the line, that is, `/k vcvars.bat x86_amd64 x64`

It is a lot easier to do

```
cmd /k " "vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 & "crosscompile.bat" x64"
```

Initialize variables, and then call the compile bat.

**edited** this is the command line i use for testing.

```
"%comspec%" /k " "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 & "c:\testvc.bat" x86"
```

Comment: No that defeats the purpose, crosscompile is feeding INTO the command prompt created by vcvars.bat (with environment variables setup to support it). Your proposed solution will make crosscompile run AFTER the vcvars.bat completes and it won't run.

Comment: @rboy, my code is starting `cmd.exe`, and tells this command prompt to execute `vcvars.bat`, that will set the variables and once this batch file ends, inside the same cmd prompt, with the variables set, execute the second batch file. Why will this approach fail?

Comment: Here's what happens
D:\x> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
"" x86_amd64   & crosscompile.bat x64
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 cross tools.
D:\x>

Comment: It only executes vcvvarsall.bat and then opens a new cmd prompt. BTW I don't see any vcvars.bat

Comment: @rboy, I have included the command line I'm using to test it. It is working for me. Please, look at the quotes: Is a full quoted command with quoted elements inside it.

Comment: AWESOME that worked, it was the location of the quotes that was making the difference. Thanks. One more change however needs to be made with you code, if I change the < to & I also need to change the /k to /c otherwise cmd won't exit when the command is complete.